# Importing All Modules in a file and Use them

Tags: javascript

I have a lot of modules in my project and I want to import them in a single file. I will transfer the Modules.js file to other files. Example:

modules.js :

```
const react = require("react")
const reactDOM = require("react-native")
const babel = require("babel")
const jquery = require("./jquery.min.js")
```

app.js:

```
const modules = require("./modules.js")

reactDOM.render(<h1>Hello,World</h1>,parentElem)
```

Comment: If you are using Node.js, `require` will solve your problem. If you are in a browser environment, you should use a module bundler such as `parcel` or `webpack`. Then you will be able to use ECMAScript `import` and `export` stataments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I want. And now I remember I should answer my own question.

my modules file :

```
function loadmodule(src) {
    elem = document.createElement("script")
    elem.src = src
    document.head.appendChild(elem)
}

loadmodule(<jquery-file>)
```

my file :

```
import {} from "modules.js"

console.log($) //is jquery loaded it returns an object
```